# How to change Magento's Soap Address Location to HTTPS

Tags: web-services, magento, wsdl

I am trying to change our wsdl to use a secure URL as the end point.  We are using the V2, WSI Compliant API and this is the line I am trying to change:

```
 <soap:address location="http://mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/"/>
```

I want to change it to:

```
 <soap:address location="https://mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/"/>
```

I really need to find out where the {{var wsdl}} is being passed in.  I have tried hard coding it in one place, but the way the wsdl is being compiled (much like the config is generated), it appends the soap address (and has both the secure and unsecure in the final product).  That's not really the way I wanted to do it, anyway.  I'm wondering if there's a design template that's driving all of this where I could declare a new variable or reset the wsdl.url bit. I've tried changing some code (just to see if this was the origin of the url) in Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Adapter_Soap and Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap to no avail. Does anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured this out and it was much easier than I expected.  This is accomplished by going to System->Configuration->Web->Secure->Use Secure URLs in Admin = Yes.